# Integral Calculus. Overlapping volume

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I wondering whether there is a more efficient and not overly complicated way to approach the solution...

If the volume V of the solid generated when the region enclosed by the curve 
$y=x^2-2x$ and the line $y=2x$ is rotated about the x-axis.

[Sol] Finding the x-coordinates of the point of intersection of the curve and the line

$x^2-2x=2x$

$x^2-4x=0$

$x(x-4)=0$

Therefore, $x=0,4$

When the region is rotated about the x-axis, there is an overlapping part. This overlapping is caused by the region below the x-axis and should be disregarded in the calculation of the volume

Volume = $V=\pi \int^4_0{[2x]^2} dx - \pi \int^4_2{[x^2-2x]^2} dx$

=$\pi \int^4_0{[4x]} dx - \pi \int^4_2{[x^4-4x^3+4x^2]} dx$

=$\pi \left.\left[\frac{4x^3}{3} \right] \right|^{4}_{0}$ - $\pi \left.\left[\frac{x^5}{5}-x^4+\frac{4x^3}{3} \right] \right|^{4}_{2}$

=$\pi(\frac{256}{3}-0)-\pi(\frac{1024}{5}-256+\frac{256}{3})-(\frac{32}{5}-16+\frac{32}{3})]$

=$\frac{784}{15} \pi$

Comment: Please use MathJax, this is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've still new to Mathjax. Hope this is slightly better